# Manga where an alien is sent to Earth to learn about it and is at school with a girl

Tags: story-identification, manga

I have recently been reading *Raise wa Tanin ga li* and it sparked an interest in a previous manga that I had read a while ago.

It was about a love story between an alien boy who had blonde hair and a young girl with black/brown(?) hair. I believe they were situated within a school environment, in which the male was sent to learn about Earth, or something of the sort. I think that the female’s name started with a "P", and the only thing I remember about her is that she was chubby as a child, and that her bellybutton was brought up once? The male is very supernaturally strong. He is very sweet and worries about "P" a lot, and is clingy. He acts like a child.

Comment: You have a good start here but this is quite a general description, can you remember anything unique to this or any specific plot points? Anything else you can remember please do not hesitate to [edit] it in, all information will help us find this for you! You also state _"I had read a while ago."_ Can you be more specific of how long ago that was?

Comment: Perhaps it'd also be better if you can explain the connection between *Raise wa Tanin ga Ii* and this manga and why it sparked an interest to this manga because most of us don't have any idea if it's a relevant hint or not...

Comment: Maybe [My Entire Class Was Summoned to Another World Except for Me](https://anilist.co/manga/100843/Class-ga-Isekai-Shoukan-sareta-Naka-Ore-dake-Nokotta-n-desu-ga/)? If I'm right please respond and I'll write a proper answer.